# using tbb atomic operations in Xeon Phi

Tags: tbb, xeon-phi

I'm using `tbb` `compare_and_swap` operation in Xeon Phi in a lock-free algorithm. Since Xeon Phi is an in order machine, it doesn't support `sfence` operation. So will the atomic operations work correctly on Xeon Phi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they definitely work correctly, most of TBB itself is based on the atomic operations. And `sfence` is not required for atomic operations to work correctly, it's a standalone memory barrier while atomic operations imply memory barriers themselves. TBB doesn't use `sfence` even on the regular Xeons, it uses `mfence` for full memory fence instead. For Xeon Phi, it is substituted by no-op atomic operation, e.g. mic_common.h of TBB contains the following definitions:

```
/** Intel(R) Many Integrated Core Architecture does not support mfence and pause instructions **/
#define __TBB_full_memory_fence() __asm__ __volatile__("lock; addl $0,(%%rsp)":::"memory")
#define __TBB_Pause(x) _mm_delay_32(16*(x))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain the difference between `sfence` and `mfence`. Since MIC is in order, would it mean that the cost of performing a Compare_and_swap be lesser compared to the out of order machine like the Xeons?

Comment: sfence serializes only stores, not loads. An since Intel memory model implies every stores except non-temporal are ordered, it has very limited usage. See [this blog](http://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/intel-memory-ordering-fence-instructions-and-atomic-operations/) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Also when I declare a variable as TBB::atomic I don't have to add the extra volatile to it right?

Comment: sure, volatile is implied by tbb::atomic